# Asp.Net MVC - ViewModel vs Domain Model vs Entity Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Have been through many artciles, but didn't get enough clarity on the usage of the 3 different models mentioned. As we know,

View Model - is used to bind the data to specific view

Domain Model - used in the Business layer class to frame the required data and pass it to Action / Controller

Entity Model - Entities provided by EntityFramework (replica of tables in Database)

Now the question is, can we use the Domain model to directly bind the data to the Views?

In case we have to explilcity build the View Model, we need to write the logic in the Action / Controller. I.e., get the data from Business layer using Domain Model and using that, build the View Model. Is this a good practice?

Also, can I use some of Domain models in View Model? Example, my View needs data from Two Domain Models, can I create a View Model and wrap these two Domain models in that View Model?

Comment: Quick explanation: 1) Yes, but it's not good practice. 2) As a common practice, you can build viewmodel from data model. 3) Yes, you can combine one or more data model into a viewmodel which interacts with view. At the end, your question still very broad there.

Answer (score 3):

From my view I will never use Domain model to bind data to view as it not good in maintainability and will introduce maintainability complexities.

Comment: Yes it's work for me.

Comment: I am glad to here that

Comment: We should be mindful about the performance also right? We are converting between the entities twice - from entity model to domain model and then from domain model to view model. This will have impact on the performance?